# Orderby on model class having more than one field Django

Tags: python-3.x, django-models, django-templates

If the Model class in django has more than one field for Example

```
Class Sheet(models.Model) :
    Question= models.Charfield() 
    answer=models.Charfield()
    Date=models.DateTimefield()
```

Then how would be the syntax for ordering and capturing only Question field data?

Comment: What does "and capturing" mean please?

Comment: Capturing Question field means getting shorted Question field data from the sheet object.

Comment: q=Sheet.objects.order_by('Date') working with class having one field Question only, giving shorted Question data,but when I add one more field answer then what shall be syntax for getting shorted/ordered Question data.

Comment: I'm still a little unsure what you're trying to do here. Do you mean you want to order the `Sheet` model by question and then answer?